# Find the limits for the following triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

The problem goes as follows: $$\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}(x^2-z^2)\, dx\,dy\,dz, $$where $\mathrm{E}$ is defined by $x, y,z \ge 0$
and $x+y+z \le 1$.
I'm have difficulties finding the limits in order to solve the triple integral. Do I use spherical or cylindrical coordinates?
How do I know which of the two to use for future problems? Or does it not matter?

Edit: I have not been able to calculate the integral, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Spherical or cylindrical ? Obviously not !

$$E=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3\mid x\in [0,1], y\in [0,1-x], z\in [0,1-x-y]\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I have actually gotten these same limits before but was confused when I've asked a friend who said that I should always use cylindrical or spherical coordinates for triple integrals. Does this mean that I can solve the integral with these mentioned limits?

Comment: Try and see ;-)

Comment: Alright! I'll try calculating without first :)

Comment: It looks very easy to just find the limits without spherical or cylindrical coordinates and then calculate the integral, am I missing something? Can you please explain when to use them? Do I seriously just calculate the integral of the limits mentioned above?

Comment: I can't provide a better answer than : use them whenever it's necessary. @18929371

Comment: I know that you should have the limit with most variables first that's why the function becomes dzdydx, but I still can't calculate the answer for the integral :(

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* The condition $x, y, z\ge 0$ restricts you to the first octant. Then the equation $x+y+z=1$ defines the plane which intersects the axes at the points $(0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 0).$ Finally, the inequality $x+y+z\le 1$ says you are interested in the finite region bounded by the first octant and the plane. Can you find your limits now?

Comment: I have calculated x and y limits in the are in xy plan and got the following limits: $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1-x$ and z extended in the z axes $z \ge 1-x-y$. Is this correct? Does this mean that there is no need to calculate using spherical and cylindrical coordinates? If this is the case, do you mind helping understand when to use them to avoid future confusion.

Comment: @18929371 You don't need to convert to other coordinates here -- that unnecessarily complicates things. Use coordinate transformations whenever they're likely to be more useful than not.